# provided key element does not match the schema error in DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

When I'm trying to get data from DynamoDb I'm getting **ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema** error.

Both the case for getUser & validateUsername is not working, I tried many ways to solve it but nothing seems to be working. My lambda is working on node 14.x.

Here is my lambda code:

```
// GET USER BY ID
async function getUser(userId) {
    const params = {
        TableName: DYNAMO_DB_TABLE_NAME,
        Key: {
            'id': {S: userId}
        }
    };
    return await DYNAMO_DB.get(params).promise()
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return generateUserResponse(response?.Item, true);
    }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
        return generateUserResponse(null, false);
    })
} 

// GET USER BY USERNAME
async function validateUsername(username) {
    console.log(username)
    const params = {
        TableName: DYNAMO_DB_TABLE_NAME,
        Key: {
            'id': username.toLowerCase()
        }
    };
    console.log(params);
    return await DYNAMO_DB.get(params).promise()
    .then((response) => {
        if (response && response?.Item) {
            return generateUserResponse(true, true);
        } else {
            return generateUserResponse(false, true);
        }
    }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
        return generateUserResponse(null, false);
    })
}
```

Comment: show your table definition

Comment: Partition key
id (String)

Sort key
username (String)

@Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is having a sort key, you need to pass both partition key and sort key in the [get](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.02) request.

If you only wants to get all the items with only partition key, use [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html) operation of dynamodb.

```
dynamoDocumentDb.get({
        TableName: DYNAMO_DB_TABLE_NAME,
        Key: {
            'pk': userId,
            'sk': '<sk value>'
        }
})
```

Comment: What to do if I'm using some other key which is neither partition key not sort key?

Comment: You need to do scan operation. Which is going to cost more. Better solution will be to create a secondary index on the column and using get or query operation on new index.

Comment: I used GSI and it worked. @nirvana124